# Why is $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin{(N+1/2)(x-y)}}{\sin{\frac{(x-y)}{2}}}dy=2\pi$?

Tags: real-analysis

Why is $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{  \sin{(N+\frac{1}{2})(x-y)}  }{  \sin(\frac{x-y}{2})}dy=2\pi$$?

For some reason it seems that $$ \frac{  \sin{(N+\frac{1}{2})(x-y)}  }{  \sin(\frac{x-y}{2})}= 1 +\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})+\cos(2\frac{x-y}{2})+...+\cos(N\frac{x-y}{2})$$

Which if this is true would make answering the previous question a lot easier, but why that equality is true is a bit ambigous also.

Comment: $=1$ or $=2\pi$ ?

Comment: It should be $2\pi$!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to check that
$$D_n(x) := \sum_{k=-n}^n \exp( ik x) = \frac{\sin((n+1/2)x)}{\sin(x/2)}.$$
In fact, this is a standard fact about the Dirichlet kernel $D_n$. Thus, we have
$$\tag{1}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin((n+1/2)(x-y))}{\sin((x-y)/2)} \mathrm{d} x = \sum_{k=-n}^n \int_0^{2\pi} \exp( ik (x-y)) \, \mathrm{d} x.$$
If $k \neq 0$, we have 
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \exp( ik (x-y)) \, \mathrm{d} x = \frac{\exp(ik(2\pi -y)- \exp(-iky)}{ik} =0.$$
Thus, in (1) we have only the term $k=0$ and the contribution of this term is $2\pi$.